# New arithmetic in counting reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The day before yesterday I had **2010** rep, I got +5 yesterday, so now I'm at **2013**. Makes sense, right? (I don't see anything about downvotes on my rep page.)

Comment: The exchange rate between American and Euro rep shifted again last night.

Comment: @federicoRusso, are you able to see the shifts caused by question deletes?

Comment: Did you unaccept any answer?

Comment: @Kortuk: in recent days? No. The only thing it shows since Saturday is the +5.

Comment: @clabacchio: none that I remember :). It doesn't show anything but the +5. (Does unaccepting affect my rep?)

Comment: @FedericoRusso, yes an unaccepted answer does affect your rep but it was something different, Writng a post with a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rep not being high enough to see deleted questions seems to make it so that you cannot see the affects from a deleted question. Here is a heavily cropped picture of your rep changes, I did my best to hide secret moderator buttons and such.

[image: Image showing reputation gain previous day due to upvote and reputation loss the day after to a post being removed that was edited]

My mouse is highlighting the time of the removal event as a time stamp to give the picture more reference then yesterday and 2 days ago.

Sorry for the confusion, just another reason to work for 10k rep!

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't it make sense if we could see all of our own rep changes, regardless of rep? (I'm working on the 10k!:)

Comment: @FedericoRusso nonsense and happenstance. Honestly, I am not sure what works the best, sounds like you could feature request.